# Strange device-height value on Android

Tags: html, css

When i get `window.innerHeight` in JS script on my Android Phone i got 994px even if there is meta tag with `viewport` & `content="width=device-width, height=device-height"` defined. Shouldn't `height=device-height` make the `window.innerHeight` == `screen.height?` And why is it just 994px?

Answer (score 0):

Window innerHeight means height of a webpage excluding browser menu, search bar and toolbar.
device-height might change from window.innerHeight

check it out
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight

Comment: "Window innerHeight means height of a webpage excluding browser menu" - yes i know it. But why is it 994px?

Comment: Can You please answer my question?